# use report field to open form at current record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I had a wander around in the forum but can't find what I am looking for. It might not even be possible but as the command controls are available I suspect it will be.

I have a report which shows a series of records based on a query. The report has a field called "project number" which is the record number from the projects file. The report shows multiple records. Is it possible to set a control on the report either in layout or ideally print preview so that the user can click on the project number on the report and it opens the projects form at the record with the same project number. I have seen a few bits of code on other sites but each time the coder has commented that it did not work?

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Report controls have onClick events just like form controls and you can attach any VBA code you like to it. It will not work on Print Preview but it will work on Report View.

Comment: Many thanks. I will give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Ok got that working in a way but cannot figure out how to get the form to open at the record matching the one in the field clicked on the report. ie. lick on the lead number in the report and open the form at the same lead number. I've tried a few commands but it just comes back runtime error... I'm not a coder so working a bit blind based on other answers in the forum. ]

Comment: Done it. Thanks